# Copying a part of string to another string

Tags: c, string

I have a string of words that have word separator between them, in another string, I wanna put the words of the main string but one by one, compare the word to some other string and put it into an array of strings.

So basically I have 
1) an array of words, and
2) a string of words
 that are in the form (word-word-word...), and what I need to do is check if one of these words is in the array of words. If yes, then, delete it.
How I'm going to do that is by defining a new 'char' type variable, walking through my main sentence and as long as I haven't reached the word separator, I add the word to the new string. Using another function, I check if this one-word string exists in the array. If no, I add the word to a temp array, then free the string and repeat until the end of the sentence. but I can't seem to do it right (I have just started studying this subject of chars, arrays of chars and so)

```
void delete_words(char *words[],int n, char *sentence ){
int m=strlen(sentence);
char tmp[m];
char * str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(MAX_LEN));
int i=0,end=0,k,z;
for(k=0; k<m; k++)
{
    z=0;
    while(*sentence && sentence[i]!= WORD_SEPERATOR)
    {
        str[z]=sentence[i];
        i++;
        z++;
    }

    if(is_string_in_array(words,n,str)==false)
    {
        int len=strlen(str);
        strcpy(tmp+k,str);
        end=end+len;
        tmp[end]=WORD_SEPERATOR;
        free(str);
    }}
```

I do realize that this is completely wrong and I can find some of the mistakes, but I don't know how to fix it because as I said, it's my first homework on the subject. will be really thankful for help!

Comment: Have you tried asking your instructor?

Comment: no, just cause its Saturday.and I'm trying to finish the homework today...

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Next time, give an [MCVE] in your question

Comment: I did try that, I can spot mistakes (for example the -i- stops at the word separator after reading the first word, and so (`while(sentence[i]!= WORD_SEPERATOR`)) will always fail after the first word), what it prints in the end is just random string(to be exact it prints ┌@) . but I can't find a way to fix it. if you could point out other things or can help how to make it any better that'd be a great help! and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here `select_next_word` will iterate through string and tries to extract words one by one then we check it against the array, if it does not exist, we add it to destination string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <String.h>

void select_next_word(char **buffer, char **next_word)
{
    *next_word = *buffer;
    while(**buffer != 0)
    {
        if(**buffer == '-')
        {
            **buffer = 0;
             (*buffer)++;
            break;
        }

        (*buffer)++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    #define CHECK_ARR_SIZE  2
    char check_arr[CHECK_ARR_SIZE][32] = {"this", "test"}; //make second dim large enough
    char test[] = "this-is-a-test-string";
    char dest[32]; //be sure it is large enough
    char *next_word;
    char *temp = test;

    while(1)
    {
        select_next_word(&temp, &next_word);
        int i = 0;
        int word_found = 0;
        for( ; i < CHECK_ARR_SIZE ;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(next_word, check_arr[i]) == 0)
            {
                word_found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!word_found)
        strcat(dest, next_word);
        if(*temp == 0)
         break;
    }

    printf(dest);
}
```

Comment: What is it that the other person wasn't doing? `"This should do, have a look"` provides no insight at all. Please try and provide a bit of explanation for what the cause of the error was and what you did to fix it. Code only answers are of limited use.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand what your code does but it also doesn't seem to work. I copied it and adjusted it according to my question but it still prints a random string. that's how I copied it : @hessamhedieh

Comment: `void delete_words(char *words[],int n, char *sentence )
{
    char dest[MAX_LEN];
    char *next_word;
    char *temp =sentence;

    while(1)
    {
        select_next_word(&temp, &next_word);
        int i = 0;
        int word_found = 0;
        for( ; i < n ;i++)
        {
            if(is_string_in_array( words ,n,next_word) == true)
            {
                word_found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!word_found)
        strcat(dest, next_word);
        if(*temp == 0)
         break;
    }
    strcpy(sentence,dest);`

Comment: also, this would prints it without the word separators if I'm not wrong

Comment: @salam, the code you pasted is changed and is not my code, so maybe double check your injected code, also as u didnt stated a format for output, i could not help, maybe if you post your compete code in your original question as a edit, I can help more